# How do I increase gap between dynamically added labels in a grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, grid

I need to place "x" number of labels on a form in my WinForm app. The function below already does that. What I am missing is the ability to increase the gap between between each label without increasing the dimensions of the label. I know it is probably something simple but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out. I apologize in advance for such a silly question.

```
private void AddUserControl()
{
    int ucHeight = 60;
    int ucWidth = 320;
    int spacer = 20;
    int start_x = 10;
    int start_y = 10;
    int NumOfRows = 6;
    int NumOfColumns = 3;
    int totalProblems = 17;
    int ucCounter = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < NumOfRows; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < NumOfColumns; y++)
        {
            if (ucCounter < totalProblems)
            {
                Label myLabel = new Label();
                myLabel.Top = start_x + (x * ucHeight + spacer);
                myLabel.Left = start_y + (y * ucWidth + spacer);
                myLabel.Width = ucWidth;
                myLabel.Height = ucHeight;
                this.Controls.Add(myLabel);
                ucCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to say gap instead of gab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> myLabel.Left = start_y + (y * ucWidth + spacer);
> ```

Your parentheses are in the wrong place.  It's equivalent to:

```
var real_start_y = start_y + spacer;
myLabel.Left = real_start_y + (y * ucWidth);
```

What you want is

```
myLabel.Left = start_y + y * (ucWidth + spacer);
```

so that every column adds `spacer` separation from the previous one.

You have the same problem when calculating `Top`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're probably looking for padding, but check out [this link (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx) and you should be able to decide what's right for your requirements.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but this is in WinForm, not WPF. I thought since I used WinForm tag, it would be clear.

Comment: It has nothing to do with WPF or WinForms - padding, margins, and layout are relevant in both places as well as web development.  I simply linked you that article as I think it explains the concepts fairly well.  Good luck to you!

Comment: @MattT partly agree on layout comment, however, it is not preferable to create such static layouts in WPF.

Comment: @benPearce static layouts are rarely ideal, agreed.  Margins and padding do not necessarily lead to static layout, however.